# AngularJS Count Yes/No Values

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently working on a AngularJS / Parse.com web application

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I would like to get the total amount of Yes & No values within an Array.
e.g Yes = 3 No = 6

**Current Problems:**
I've managed to get all Yes & No values from Parse and put them into an Array but I'm unable to count the amount of Yes or No values.

Any help / advice would be helpful!

**HTML:**

```
<md-card>
  <md-card-content>
    <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" data="widgetone_data" labels="widgetone_label"></canvas>
  </md-card-content>
  {{widgetone_data | json}}
</md-card>
```

**Controller JS:**

```
dashApp.controller("dashboardCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
  $scope.parseRecommendations = [];
  $http({
      method : 'GET',url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Customers',
      headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':'xxx', 'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'xxx'}
  })
  .success(function(data, error) {
    $scope.parseResults = data.results;
    angular.forEach($scope.parseResults, function(results) {
      $scope.parseRecommendations.push(results.question_4_p1);
    });
  })
  .error(function(data, error) {alert('Failed, error code: ' + error.message);
  });

  // Recommend YES/NO
  var yesAmount = $filter('filter')($scope.parseRecommendations, { isSelected: 'yes' }).length;
  var noAmount = $filter('filter')($scope.parseRecommendations, { isSelected: 'no' }).length;
  $scope.widgetone_label = ["Yes", "No"];
  $scope.widgetone_data = [yesAmount,noAmount];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method.

Moreover, you made an error, because you start to filter your data when the controller is instantiated, but your API call is **asynchronous**, so you have to filter your data into the **.success()** callback, otherwise you will filter an **empty array**.

EDIT : To improve performance, you can count your by simulating an **hashmap**. See below

```
   dashApp.controller("dashboardCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
      $scope.parseRecommendations = [];

      var hashmap = {};

      $http({
          method : 'GET',url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Customers',
          headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':'wmWxU64vx0QgKBiNQkx9jCDNO6UZDRrM6WkxAbTL', 'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'0FHcBHZdeUJHKT8j0VQH0hQdN4TZ8qsOBxyd1rG3'}
      })
      .success(function(data, error) {
        $scope.parseResults = data.results;
        angular.forEach($scope.parseResults, function(results) {
          $scope.parseRecommendations.push(results.question_4_p1);
        });

        $scope.parseRecommendations.forEach(function(elm){
          hashmap.hasOwnProperty(elm)
          ? ++hashmap[elm]
          : hashmap[elm] = 1
        });

        //Filter yes
        var yesAmount = hashmap.yes;

        //Filter no
        var noAmount = hashmap.no;

        $scope.widgetone_label = ["Yes", "No"];
        $scope.widgetone_data = [yesAmount,noAmount];

        console.log($scope.widgetone_data);

      })
      .error(function(data, error) {alert('Failed, error code: ' + error.message);
      });
        });
```

Comment: You're welcome :). I've updated the code, so you'll do just one loop to count yes/no.